# eclipse key map on intellij

Tags: eclipse, ide, intellij-idea

I am switching to Intellij from eclipse because many people have recommended it.

I am thinking of using eclipse key map for it , but I am wondering if I should just spend some time learning the actual keymaps. Is there any advantage to way Intellij keymaps are ?

Comment: I see only one advantage. When you ask for help from IDEA user, you can get more accurate answer, because your keymap will be same.

Answer (score 6):

Beside the advantage mentioned by [chalimartines](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191727/chalimartines) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982225/eclipse-key-map-on-intellij#comment15978027_11982225) (more accurate help), the main advantage is to minimize potential conflicts with existing plugins keymaps, which could collide with your new keymap.
[Anton Arhipov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431270/anton-arhipov) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982225/eclipse-key-map-on-intellij/11984372#comment15983839_11984372) that:

> any other keymap might not cover all the cases for IntelliJ.
>   Thus, by switching the keymap, the user has a risk of limiting himself from the full potential while using IntelliJ.

The other approach, when considering the [IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) (full default keymap), is to make a simplified one, as done in "[Improved IntelliJ keymap](http://jcraane.blogspot.fr/2011/12/improved-intellij-keymap.html)" by **Jamie Craane**: see [this Reference Card](http://www.capaxit.nl/docs/IntelliJKeymapWindows.pdf).

Comment: I would also add that the eclipse key map might not cover all the cases for IntelliJ. Thus, by switching the keymap, the user has a risk of limiting himself from the full potential while using IntelliJ.

Comment: @AntonArhipov I agree, good point. I have added it to the answer for more visibility.